# WCErrorDomain Code=7007 when adding localized InfoPlist.strings

Tags: ios, iphone, watchos-2, wcsession

I have developed iPhone app with watchOS 2 app, but I met a strange problem.

Everything is ok before I localize InfoPlist.strings of watchOS 2 target (not watchOS 2 extension target).

If I localize InfoPlist.strings, the app will get the error

> Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7007 "WatchConnectivity session on
>   paired device is not reachable."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=WatchConnectivity session on paired
>   device is not reachable.}.

I have no idea why. Here is my test project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31258390/TestApp.zip

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Best way to get a sure answer would be to file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I am not sure that it only happened on my mac environment. So need some guys to check it.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to say that I've had the same issue, and I found a [radar](http://www.openradar.me/23096604) (#23096604) detailing a similar problem:

> If you have localization on the watch extension (even empty strings files), the only part of WCSession that seems to work is sending data via the applicationContext. The transferUserInfo method just queues up data and it is never sent. The sendMessage function is also unreliable in this case.
>
> *Closed as duplicate of 22682390*.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10316913)

Comment: @JulienVavasseur: I wanted to let the original poster know that he's not the only one with the problem, and that there's probably not a solution to it since a radar has been filed. Would my answer have been better off as a comment?

Comment: I think if you don't start with "I have a similar issue" (remove it) and rephrase and explain a little bit it could be an answer.